# grep and cut text from unstructured file?

Tags: awk, grep, cat, cut

From below  3lines I need to grep and cut jar file name only. 
How to grep jar name from the line and cut from there.

```
Downloading:https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.0.6.RELEASE/spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar   
    Downloaded:https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-aspects/5.0.6.RELEASE/spring-aspects-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar (46 KB at 12.6 KB/sec)
    Downloading:https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/5.0.5.RELEASE/spring-security-config-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
640/1052 KB   2580/6582 KB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F'.jar' '/.jar/{print $1".jar"}' file |awk '{print $NF}' FS=/
```

The first awk display only the lines that contain ".jar", and display them until the name of the jar file

The second awk remove everything from the beginning of the line until the las occurrence of "/", and only left the name of the jar file

Comment: This works but `cat` isn't needed. The filename can simply be added at the end of the first `awk` statement.

Comment: ok, I will edit the answer

Answer (score 3):

If your `grep` supports the `-o` (`--only-matching`) command line option, and you want to output a sequence of non-`/` characters terminating in `.jar`, then you can use

```
grep -o '[^/]*\.jar\b' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -ne 'print $1 if /([^\/]*\.jar\s)/' file
```

If you want your results in one line ( useful when trying to create an array of the names matching the pattern )

Or, print it in different lines

```
perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /([^\/]*\.jar)/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using standard `sed`:

```
$ sed -nE '/\.jar/{ s%.*/(.+\.jar).*%\1%p; }' file
spring-aop-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar
```

This finds lines that contain the string `.jar` and performs a substitution on them.  The substitution replaces the whole line with only the filename portion of the line.  It is assumed that the filename is the only thing that contains the string `.jar` on the line.